# Printing all values of two columns in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql

I have been trying to print all values of two columns of table using loop in sql stored procedure but no luck yet.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_my_procedure_name]
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
    DECLARE @User_ID INT =16  
    DECLARE @ID INT
    DECLARE @Count INT
    DECLARE @Count1 INT
    DECLARE @Code VARCHAR(500)

    SELECT @Count1= MAX(ID), @Count = MIN(ID)
    FROM ABC
    WHERE ID = 10 AND Code NOT LIKE '%ABC%' 

    WHILE (@Count <= @count1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ID = (ID), @Code = Code 
        FROM ABC 
        WHERE ID = 10 AND Code NOT LIKE '%ABC%

        PRINT @ID 
        PRINT @Code

        SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END
END
```

Also how to optimize it further as i have to traverse for 7k records

Comment: Can you explain how you think your code works, and why it isn't working as expected? I can't see why it wouldn't just set `@Count1` and `@Count` to equal 10 and then exit once `@Count` becomes 11.

Comment: Not sure I need to traverse through values of column as per filter condition and print them as output .May be i am missing something. Any help appreciated

Comment: I am sorry the ID in where clause added by mistake

Comment: OK, can you edit your question please. You still haven't really explained why the code you've written doesn't work as you expect it to. What does it do now? Why is that not correct? What would you rather it do?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, and share with us what it gives you, and what the ideal result would look like (also share some of the input rows from ABC).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [usp_my_procedure_name]
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

    SELECT Distinct ID, Code
    FROM ABC
    WHERE Code NOT LIKE '%ABC%
    ORDER BY ID

END
```